# Autocomplete for ERB in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, erb

Is there a package or snippet I can use to activate autocompletion for ERB (.html.erb) files in Sublime?

I'm not talking about shortcuts like https://github.com/eddorre/SublimeERB provides. I want to start typing "`<%`" and than Sublime to offer me the autocomplete suggestions "`<% %>, <%= %>...`" similar to what happens when I enter "`<d`" Sublime suggest the "`<div>`" tag autocompletion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I setup/use ruby on rails snippets and autocomplete in sublime text 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430026/how-do-i-setup-use-ruby-on-rails-snippets-and-autocomplete-in-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using ERB snippet, it covers major erb tags

https://github.com/matthewrobertson/ERB-Sublime-Snippets

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

https://github.com/eddorre/SublimeERB#add-keybinding

Follow the simple instructions in the README.