# What is the shortcut in Sublime text 2 for this "<%= t %>"

Tags: sublimetext2, shortcut, emmet

I don't know much about rails or sublime, but it would be amazing if there was a shortcut for this.

I have Emmet installed on my sublime but I haven't been able to find any documentation for this shortcut, mostly b/c i have no idea what it's called.

What is this called in rails or internationalization and how can I use a shortcut for this in sublime text 2

**<%= t %>**

Answer (score 0):

I actually just found the solution!

[How do I setup/use ruby on rails snippets and autocomplete in sublime text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430026/how-do-i-setup-use-ruby-on-rails-snippets-and-autocomplete-in-sublime-text-2)

It wasn't the first answer, but rather the ERB Snippets a few answers down.

Once you install the ERB Snippet via Package Control the shortcut for the above (called t helper!) is just "t" + tab